# How do I use the IDE to make and install a snap package?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development

I have built, and installed Twinkle, a VOIP program.  I have built and installed it on my Ubuntu tablet,from a click but package, but that did not install properly.  I now want to try it with a snap package.  I can't sort out how to go about it, and what tools do I need?.    Barry Drake.

Answer (score 1):

In order to build a snap package you need to know how to solve problems on your own, and [Ubuntu Tutorials](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/) can teach you some of the skills required to do this. Ubuntu Tutorials has five tutorials about how to use and build snap packages and how to use some of the snap development tools packages in the Ubuntu Snap Store. The two beginner tutorials are easy for a new recruit to understand, but you may find the three intermediate level tutorials challenging.

If you can't finish all the tutorials, then you shouldn't expect to be able to successfully build a Twinkle snap. If you run into problems following the tutorials, make sure that your installed snap packages are up-to-date. After you have finished the tutorials is when the hard part of building your own snap package starts, so be prepared for it.

Regarding the IDE, you can use the terminal and if you need to use a GUI IDE use whatever IDE you're comfortable with.

Comment: What happened to the part about actually building the Twinkle snap package? Are you going to tell me anything about that?